# Alsa problems with python2.7- Unable to open slave

Tags: sound, python, alsa, python-2.7

I am using python's module pyaudio to process sound but ALSA returns:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear

ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe

ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side

bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)

bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)

bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)

bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory

Cannot connect to server request channel

jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Alsa works fine in recording sound and playing it from terminal, but python (2.7) keeps returning these errors. I dont know if it is relevant but i can dual boot to Windows 8.1 as well.

Comment: Possibly related http://askubuntu.com/q/800134/25388

Comment: have you tried running the program as root? maybe you need to be in group `audio` or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

This can get rid of the Unknown Device messages: 
`sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and comment out `cards.pcm.{device}` where `{device}` is the unknown devices listed

this will get rid of the jack server error, not sure about the others

```
sudo apt install multimedia-jack
pulseaudio --kill
jack_control  start
```

If you get memory errors logout/login AFTER running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio MYUSERNAME
```

Make sure you log out / in, otherwise permissions won't be updated.

You may need to run:

```
jack_control  start
```

again

Comment: Not for me in a similar situation. Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/q/35652194/54964 Do you have to restart for the effect? I did not do it.

Comment: The restart (log out actually) is only needed to make `usermod` take effect. To see if it has, run `groups` and you should see `audio` listed